# Is partial page reload possible in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, gridview

I got 2 .aspx pages ,

**page one(1) to insert data** .....

**page two(2) to view data using a gridview**.

There's an **edit** button in the gridview , it will redirect the to **page(1)** and load the specific values to the **textboxes, dropdowns** according to the selected record.

Session is used to carry out the record from page(1) to page(2).

In the page load of **page(1)**, if **Session is not NULL** it will load the values to the **textboxes** and etc.

My problem is , I have enabled **Autopostback=true** in one of the **dropdowns**,(to enable few more *textbox's to appear when specific options are selected*).

So when those options are selected page will be reloaded,when reloading it will **load the specific values to the textboxes** .... as the Session is not null. And the purpose of dropdown is not fulfilled because it keeps loading values to the textboxes , but **not enabling the textboxes** which i need to appear + the value of the selected dropdown doesnt get changed to the selected value as it loads values from the database to the dropdown too.

Any solutions ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386454%28v=vs.100%29.aspx for partial page updates. You can run server side code on client side objects. Also consider turning autopostback OFF, and just handling the extra textboxes via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I sounds like you're looking for a partial postback solution.
The UpdatePanel should solve this for you:
http://www.encodedna.com/2013/02/aspdotnet.postback-updatepanel.htm

Comment: well , i am kind of new to this stuff. Does this provide a way so that only specific Controllers would get updated ?

Comment: Yes it does. Just follow the example... they're doing something there with a dropdownlist, very similar to what you're trying to do. Basically, you put the dropdown, along with any other controls which need to change inside the update panel, then when the dropdown triggers a postback, on the items inside the update panel get posted back.